# Invoke smart contract by address, from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, web3j

I'm trying out a publisher-subscriber smart contracts in ganache.

Both the publisher and subscriber work independently, but when I try to invoke the subscriber from publisher through the contract address, I get below **error**:

> "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert".

Been searching on the net, but didn't find any solution.

---

Here is my code:

> **Producer.sol**

```
//Mocking subscriber contract

contract Receiver {

function notify(uint count) returns(uint);

function getCurrentCounter() constant returns(uint);

}

//Publisher

contract Producer {

uint private count;
uint private subscriberCount;
mapping(uint => Subscriber) subscribers;
event CountIncreased(uint num);

struct Subscriber {
    string subscriberName;
    address subscriberAddress;
}

function Producer() {
    count = 0;
    subscriberCount = 0;
}

function increaseCount() returns(uint,address) {
    count++;
    Receiver receiver = Receiver(subscribers[0].subscriberAddress);
    receiver.notify(count);
    CountIncreased(count);
    return (count,subscribers[0].subscriberAddress);
}

function addSubscriber(string name, address subAddress) {
    subscriberCount++;
    subscribers[subscriberCount].subscriberName = name ;
    subscribers[subscriberCount].subscriberAddress = subAddress ;
}

function removeSubscriber(string subscriberName) {
    for (uint i=0; i<subscriberCount; i++) {
        Subscriber sub = subscribers[i];
        if(keccak256(sub.subscriberName) == keccak256(subscriberName)) {
            delete subscribers[i];
            subscriberCount--;
        }
    }

}


}
```

> **Subscriber.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Bookkeeping {

uint counter;

function Bookkeeping() {
    counter = 0;
}

function notify(uint count) returns(uint) {
    counter = count+5;
    return counter;
}

function getCurrentCounter() constant returns(uint) {
    return counter;
}


}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you use `call` instead of `sendTransaction` when calling `addSubscriber` before `increaseCount`?

Comment: You have to be more precise. The error happened when you called which function?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you call `addSubscriber` first and then call `increaseCount`.

At the beginning subscriberCount is 0, when you `addSubscriber` it will increment to 1

```
function addSubscriber(string name, address subAddress) {
    subscriberCount++;
```

And will store the subscriber info at `subscribers[1]`, leaving `subscribers[0]` with default zero values

```
    subscribers[subscriberCount].subscriberName = name ;
    subscribers[subscriberCount].subscriberAddress = subAddress ;
}
```

Now when you try to call `notify` from `increaseCount` it will fail

```
Receiver receiver = Receiver(subscribers[0].subscriberAddress);
```

Because `subscriberAddress` is zero.

---

I'd suggest to move Receiver to its own file and include them in both Producer and Subscriber, and make Bookkeeping inherit from it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. As you said, it was more a logical issue. I incremented the subscriberCount after adding to mapping, looks like this: function addSubscriber(string name, address subAddress) {
        subscribers[subscriberCount].subscriberName = name ;
        subscribers[subscriberCount].subscriberAddress = subAddress ;
        subscriberCount++;
    }